# SQL Syntax Error

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have java code which connect to MySQL and retrive data. I have following code and it always give `SQLSyntaxErrorException` and says there is syntax error in line 1. I cant understand why. Please help me. I can sure the names are correct.

```
private void saveDetails(int slct) throws SQLException {

        if(slct == ADD_NEW_RECORD) {
            String query = "INSERT INTO emp(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement st = Main.db.con.prepareStatement(query);
            st.setString(1, "epfno");
            st.setString(2, "fname");
            st.setString(3, "lname");
            st.setString(4, "sex");
            st.setString(5, "nid");
            st.setString(6, "address");
            st.setString(7, "birthday");
            st.setString(8, "position");
            st.setString(9, "tpno");
            st.setString(10, "fathername");
            st.setString(11, "mothername");
            st.setString(12, "m_status");
            st.setString(13, "comments");
            st.setString(14, "photo_id");
            st.setInt(15, emp.epfno);
            st.setString(16, emp.fname);
            st.setString(17, emp.lname);
            st.setInt(18, emp.sex);
            st.setString(19, String.copyValueOf(emp.nid));
            st.setString(20, emp.address);
            st.setDate(21, emp.birthday);
            st.setString(22, emp.position);
            st.setString(23, emp.tpno);
            st.setString(24, emp.fathername);
            st.setString(25, emp.mothername);
            st.setBoolean(26, emp.m_status);
            st.setString(27, emp.comments);
            st.setString(28, emp.photo_id);

            st.execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the error stack trace or log output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to set the *field names* as parameters - you can't do that. You can only specify *values* as parameters. So basically your first 14 `setString` calls should go away, and you should put those field names in the SQL:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO emp(epfno, fname, lname, sex, nid, address, "
             + "birthday, position, tpno, fathername, mothername, m_status, "
             + "comments, photo_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

st.setInt(1, emp.epfno);
st.setString(2, emp.fname);
st.setString(3, emp.lname);
// etc
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot parameterize the name of the columns, so your SQL needs to look something like this:
`INSERT INTO emp(epfno, fname, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot specify column names as parameters. Try spelling them out in your query:

```
INSERT INTO emp(epfno, fname, lname,...
```

and getting rid of the first half of the `st.setXXX` calls.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass in column names as ? parameters. You would need to name the columns in your query and only pass the values in as parameters